# definite integral of a derivative of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I got this question on the finals review:
[image: I got this question on the finals review:]

I am not sure how this can be done, as the integral is bound by 2 numbers, which will yield a number (area under curve), but then it asks to take derivate, and then another integral, and I have no idea how this will work, so if someone can walk me through this question I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Also the homework tag is not there so I cant tag as homework.

Comment: What is the derivative of a constant?

Comment: @copper.hat oooohhhh I see. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You integrate some integrable function and you get some number (doesn't matter what). Then you take the derivative of the number, which is $0$. Then the integral of $0$ is $0$, so your final answer is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon avid19's answer, you let $C = \int_1^5e^\sqrt x + x^3 \,dx$

Since $C$ is a constant it follows that $\frac{dC}{dx}=0 $

Thus the integral can be evaluated as below: $$\int_0^2 ( \frac{d}{dx} \int_1^5e^\sqrt x + x^3 \, dx) \, dx=\int_0^20 \, dx=0$$